# Enter android immersive mode

Tags: android, react-native

I need to enter android immersive mode in my react-native app, but when I try `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE)` I got a lot of errors during compilation. I don't know anything about native android development and do it blindfold. So can you please briefly explain what and where I need to past to make it work.

Comment: What is your minimum api level? That's new in Android 4.4 (API Level 19) You might want to read this: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html. Otherwise you need to read the error if you want to know what's wrong.

Comment: API level 19. I don't know anything about Android development but as I can see it's syntax errors. And I have seen this page but I don't know where to use this: in main activity or create other file? And how to use it? May I create void or past this in something like onclick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need only to automatically hide android navigation buttons on app start so it's enough to add few lines of code in `MainActivity.java`:

```
@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // прячем панель навигации
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // прячем строку состояния
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
    super.onStart();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what about adding android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"  in your android manifest xml file??